# Scraping with Beautiful Soup and Python to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

Trying to scrape floor sizes (in sq ft) and lot sizes (in hectares) from listings on a real estate website using Beautiful Soup and Selenium.

The floor sizes print fine in the console

[image]

but when writing to a csv file the the 'sq ft' info under the floor size column is not extracted

[image]

It seems if 'sq ft' is found by BS4 in the ID element after the the one stipulated, that is returned instead and all other 'sq ft' text is passed over on every other url when writing to the csv. As you can see on ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxyPk.png)) two of the listings have this, despite those two links having hectares as well:

http://property.shw.co.uk/propertyInfo/11080/145151-London-Road-Croydon--CR0-2RG
http://property.shw.co.uk/propertyInfo/16162/Public-HouseRestaurant-Site-Westvale-Park-Horley-Surrey--RH6-0HJ

Can someone explain why the sq ft are printed on the console but not written to the csv? Any help would be appreciated.

Relevant HTML where CP2_CPContent_conDetails1_divDetails is relevant locator for floor sizes and lot sizes:

```
<div id="CP2_CPContent_conDetails1_divDetails">
                0.3 Acres <br>(0.12 Hectares)
                <div class="clear"></div>

                <div id="CP2_CPContent_conDetails1_divDes" class="divInfo">
                      Potential building size of 6,458 sq ft (600 sq m)<br>
                </div>
```

Code as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
shw_search_url = "http://property.shw.co.uk/searchproperties/Level2-0/Level1-0-181-236-167-165/Units/Development-or-House-and-Flat-or-Investment-or-Land-or-Office-or-Other/UnitIds-0/For-Sale"
driver.get(shw_search_url)


#identify and extract listing links from each page
def get_house_links(url, driver, pages=3):
    house_links = []
    driver.get(url)
    for i in range(pages):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        listings = soup.find_all("a", class_="L")
        page_data = [row['href'] for row in listings]
        house_links.append(page_data)
        time.sleep(np.random.lognormal(0, 1))
        next_button = soup.select('img[src*="propNext"]')
        if next_button:
            next_button = next_button[0].find_parent('a')
            next_button_link = 'http://property.shw.co.uk' + next_button['href']
            driver.get(next_button_link)
    return house_links

#get html data from url and return as object
def get_html_data(url, driver):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(np.random.lognormal(0,1))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def get_lot_size(soup):
    try:
        for element in soup.find_all('div', {'id':'CP2_CPContent_conDetails1_divDetails'}):
            lot_size = element.find_next(text=re.compile('Hectares'))
        lot_size = lot_size.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
        print(lot_size)
        return lot_size
    except:
        return 'NA'

def get_floor_size(soup):
    try:
        for element in soup.find('div', {'id': 'CP2_CPContent_conDetails1_divDetails'}):
            floor_size = element.find_next(text=re.compile('sq ft'))
        print(floor_size)
        return floor_size
    except:
        return 'NA'

def flatten_list(house_links):
    house_links_flat = []
    for sublist in house_links:
        for item in sublist:
            house_links_flat.append(item)
    return house_links_flat

def get_house_data(driver, house_links_flat):
    house_data = []
    for link in house_links_flat:
        soup = get_html_data(link, driver)
        floor_size = get_floor_size(soup)
        lot_size = get_lot_size(soup)
        house_data.append([floor_size, lot_size])

    return house_data

house_links_3pages = get_house_links(shw_search_url,driver,pages=3)
house_links_flat = flatten_list(house_links_3pages)
house_data_3pages = get_house_data(driver,house_links_flat)


#open and write results to csv
file_name = "SHW %s_%s.csv" % (str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                           str(time.strftime("%H:%M%S")))
columns = ["Floor_Size", "Lot_Size"]
pd.DataFrame(house_data_3pages, columns = columns).to_csv(
    file_name, index = False, encoding = "UTF-8"
)
```

---

Comment: use `print()` in different places to see values in variables - maybe you forgot to add them to list/dataframe.

Comment: or maybe you have it in different column  - ie. with address.

Comment: you should always use `except Exception as ex: print('ex:', ex)` - maybe you have error which makes all this problem and you don't even know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no problem to get `Hectares` with your code.

I had problem with `sq ft` - it doesn't even display it. All because you used `find()` instead of `find_all()` in

```
 for element in soup.find()
```

but `find()` doesn't return list with elements but single element and then `for` doesn't get this element from list but it gets probably its children and it searchs `sq ft` in wrong places.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import time
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
shw_search_url = "http://property.shw.co.uk/searchproperties/Level2-0/Level1-0-181-236-167-165/Units/Development-or-House-and-Flat-or-Investment-or-Land-or-Office-or-Other/UnitIds-0/For-Sale"
driver.get(shw_search_url)


#identify and extract listing links from each page
def get_house_links(url, driver, pages=3):
    house_links = []
    driver.get(url)
    for i in range(pages):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        listings = soup.find_all("a", class_="L")
        page_data = [row['href'] for row in listings]
        house_links.append(page_data)
        time.sleep(np.random.lognormal(0, 1))
        next_button = soup.select('img[src*="propNext"]')
        if next_button:
            next_button = next_button[0].find_parent('a')
            next_button_link = 'http://property.shw.co.uk' + next_button['href']
            driver.get(next_button_link)
    return house_links

#get html data from url and return as object
def get_html_data(url, driver):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(np.random.lognormal(0,1))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def get_lot_size(soup):
    try:
        for element in soup.find_all('div', {'id':'CP2_CPContent_conDetails1_divDetails'}):
            lot_size = element.find_next(text=re.compile('Hectares'))
            if lot_size:
                lot_size = lot_size.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
                lot_size = lot_size.strip()
            print('lot_size:', lot_size)
        return lot_size
    except Exception as ex:
        print("EX:", ex)
        return 'NA'

def get_floor_size(soup):
    try:
        for element in soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'CP2_CPContent_conDetails1_divDetails'}):
            floor_size = element.find_next(text=re.compile('sq ft'))
            if floor_size:
                floor_size = floor_size.strip()
            print('floor_size:', floor_size)
        return floor_size
    except Exception as ex:
        print("EX:", ex)
        return 'NA'

def flatten_list(house_links):
    house_links_flat = []
    for sublist in house_links:
        for item in sublist:
            house_links_flat.append(item)
    return house_links_flat

def get_house_data(driver, house_links_flat):
    house_data = []
    for link in house_links_flat:
        soup = get_html_data(link, driver)
        floor_size = get_floor_size(soup)
        lot_size = get_lot_size(soup)
        house_data.append([floor_size, lot_size])
        print('-------------------')

    return house_data

house_links_3pages = get_house_links(shw_search_url,driver,pages=3)
house_links_flat = flatten_list(house_links_3pages)
house_data_3pages = get_house_data(driver,house_links_flat)


#open and write results to csv
file_name = "SHW %s_%s.csv" % (str(time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")),
                           str(time.strftime("%H:%M%S")))
columns = ["Floor_Size", "Lot_Size"]
pd.DataFrame(house_data_3pages, columns = columns).to_csv(
    file_name, index = False, encoding = "UTF-8"
)
```

CSV:

```
Floor_Size,Lot_Size
,0.21 Hectares
7342 sq ft,
1665 sq ft,
"The existing property extends to approximately 2,290 sq m (24,649 sq ft) GIA and sits within an L-shaped site extending to approximately 0.6 acres (0.25 hectares). Fronting London Road is a four storey commercial building, built as a garage with offices above which is currently occupied by a motor company at ground floor level, and by a church across the upper floors and basement. To the rear of the site fronting Montague Road are a number of single storey industrial buildings, currently occupied by a hand carwash. The remainder of the front forecourt and rear of the site is hard standing, predominantly used as car parking.",0.25 Hectares
4672 to 20302 sq ft,
,0.36 Hectares
,0.08 Hectares
,0.18 Hectares
2325 sq ft,
,0.02 Hectares
5288 sq ft,
0 sq ft,
,0.36 Hectares
,0.18 Hectares
"*  Potential building size of 6,458 sq ft (600 sq m)",0.12 Hectares
1258 to 5385 sq ft,
,0.13 Hectares
3600 sq ft,
,0.24 Hectares
6781 to 6871 sq ft,
```

Comment: If I wanted to write the URLs from house_links to the csv, could you tell me a way of doing this? @furas

Comment: `house_data.append([link, floor_size, lot_size])` and `columns = ["Link", "Floor_Size", "Lot_Size"]` and it should add link to CSV

Comment: Thanks a lot @furas! Really appreciate your help